# Reversing random generation function

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, hashcode

I have a random generation function that creates a string of random numbers based on a seed.

```
hash_ = '1'
for i in range(5):
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(hash_.encode("utf-8"))
    hash_ = m.hexdigest()
    print(hash_)
```

This outputs

```
6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b
e0bc614e4fd035a488619799853b075143deea596c477b8dc077e309c0fe42e9
d6a804981ea7ce374acc21c9a8bf82f50b684b0ea4bdf8b26a7a775291aaf7a6
ad376767fc04814220cc25c79b2777cd14704f23f1830318b5bd9eb97e4fedf6
b80de1ab9d0903823cc10fd5b2ba57616b339a69313b4d3e23363dbea6579cd6
```

And will output this every single time

My question is if it would be possible and how could I possibly reverse this function.
So I start the function with:
`hash_ = b80de1ab9d0903823cc10fd5b2ba57616b339a69313b4d3e23363dbea6579cd6`
and the last hash it would output would be:
`6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b`

Just wondering if this is even possible thanks for all help :)

Comment: You don't reverse hashes, they are explicitly designed to not be reversible.

Comment: Cryptographic hashes are especially designed so that it shouldn't be possible. In fact it may be computable with an incredible effort and enough time (thousands of years or even much more!).Practical answer: No.

Comment: shame :( thanks for the help

Comment: Depends on the initial value of `hash_`. If it is something short and possibly in a dictionary, it it fairly easy to use that code to write a brute forcer. Keep in mind that Python is usually too slow for such a task since it is interpreted.

Comment: "shame", no, believe me, you don't want them to be.  If you want it to be reversible, you use encryption, `hashing != encryption`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `for .. else ...` grammar.
After all loop completed( if no error), will execute the code.
Like this:

```py
hash_ = '1'
for i in range(5):
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(hash_.encode("utf-8"))
    hash_ = m.hexdigest()
else:
    print(hash_)
```